# Group models from different app/object into one Admin block

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to group models from different apps into 1 admin block?

For example, my structure is

```
project/
  review/
    models.py -  class Review(models.Model):
  followers/
    models.py -  class Followers(models.Model):
    admin.py
```

In `followers/admin.py`, I call

```
 admin.site.register(Followers)
 admin.site.register(Review)
```

This is to group them inside 1 admin block for administrators to find things easily.

I tried that, but `Review` model isn't showing up inside `Followers` admin block and I couldn't find documentation about this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Django Admin groups Models to admin block by their apps which is defined by `Model._meta.app_label`. Thus registering `Review` in `followers/admin.py` still gets it to app `review`.

So make a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) of `Review` and put it in the 'review' app

```
class ProxyReview(Review):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True    
        # If you're define ProxyReview inside review/models.py,
        #  its app_label is set to 'review' automatically.
        # Or else comment out following line to specify it explicitly               
        # app_label = 'review'

        # set following lines to display ProxyReview as Review
        # verbose_name = Review._meta.verbose_name
        # verbose_name_plural = Review._meta.verbose_name_plural


# in admin.py
admin.site.register(ProxyReview)
```

Also, you could put `Followers` and `Review` to same app or set same `app_label` for them.

Customize admin view or use 3rd-part dashboard *may* achieve the goal also.

Comment: Works fine even for django 3. Thanks

Comment: Can also be used to display some profiles one way and other profiles another based on some flag in the profile or a related model.