# Display models of same app in different app django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-apps

I have an app `other` in django. I have models like `PaymentMethods` , `Currencies` , `ReasonCodes` , `DeviceInfo` etc in this app.. I want to display few models under a different heading. How can I do this? Do we have to use a library? Tried using `django-modeladmin-reorder` library. But it doesnt work. Note : I am using Django 1.8 and a library `django-material` for the admin interface.

Eg of what I would want. `Other` is my app name. It has 4 models under it.

`PaymentMethods`,
`Currencies`,
`ReasonCodes` ,
`DeviceInfo`

Now in the default admin, all the 4 models are displayed under `other` app.

I need to display like this,
verbose name of `other` will be 'payments' and under this i would want 
`PaymentMethods`,
`Currencies`

and another section named 'device info' and under this, 
`ReasonCodes` ,
`DeviceInfo`
should be shown.

Comment: can you give some example of what you want

Comment: @Exprator - I have edited my question.

Comment: i guess normally it isnt possible, but you can make a proxy app and in its admin you can call the models from the other app to show, and the other can be put with verbose name in other app in admin

Comment: I suppose this can be achieved with this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561305/7787478.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `admin/base_site.html` and write your own version of `{% block sidenav_header %}`