# Django Admin: show multiple apps together in one section?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working on a Django API for a webshop, and I organized the models and views into different apps: one for orders, one for baskets, one for products, and one for offers. Now I want to add these models to the admin site, but I don't want it to show up as four different sections each with one model to manage. Instead I want a new "Shop" section where I show the models for all these apps.

So instead of this:

[image]

I want both models in one common section. Is this possible?

I tried setting the same verbose name in both app's `apps.py` file, but that just results in two sections with the same name:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`django-modeladmin-reorder`** <sup>[PyPI]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-modeladmin-reorder/) for this. You can configure this with the `ADMIN_REORDER` setting:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # …,
    'admin_reorder',
    # …
)

# …

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # …,
    'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder',
    # …
)

# …

ADMIN_REORDER = (
    {'label': 'product', 'models': ('product.Product', 'order.Order')},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561091/group-models-from-different-app-object-into-one-admin-block)

What you should do is create a proxy model in your admin.py for the model you want in the other admin page like this:

```
class OrderProxy(Order):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True    

admin.site.register(OrderProxy)
```